# Can I send my journal article (under review) for a invited Elsevier book (not-to-be-refereed) chapter?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, books

I just got an invitation from an editor of a non-refereed book. Is it considered self plagiarism if I send one of my journal article to the book?

The book is hard to define. It is more like a textbook rather than a review volume.

Comment: I hardly see how a kind of a textbook can accommodate a research article. You should better rewrite it in an appropriate form, automatically avoiding (except for figures. .) issues such a copyright and self plagiarism.

Answer (score 2):

If you had published your paper on a journal and you had transferred the copyright to that journal, it's a violation of copyright. And typically you transfer the copyright at the time of submission.

If you want to republish your paper somewhere else, you should first ask permission to the copyright owner.

Beware, moreover, that most of the invitations to "publish your research" in a book come from predatory publishers. In case, you don't want to send them any of your works.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The book publisher is Elsevier.

Answer (score 1):

**Chances are, yes.** From your description it's likely the editor is looking for a review volume. That means that, even if you hold the copyright, the odds are the book's editor is looking for novel content (i.e. previously unpublished work). If you've already published something elsewhere, that rules it out from the book as well.